# In Office 2016, how can I change the default attachment option from 'preview' to 'open'?

Tags: attachments, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-office-2016

On Office 2016 (running Windows 7 64-bit), I find the preview pane for Outlook is too small to be useful for documents, and it's annoying having to use the drop down and select "Open" every time instead of just clicking the file.

How can I change the default attachment option from 'Preview' to 'Open'?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just double click the attachment and it will open without going to the preview pane first. Note that you will get a security popup the first time asking if you would like to open the file. If you uncheck the box at the bottom, you shouldn't get this popup again for this file type. (I leave mine checked since it is my work account)

**EDIT**

Check out [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother/cannot-open-attachments-via-double-click/2664a2c2-cb80-40f2-a123-4a44c5f64568) link for the double click issue. From the accepted answer:

> SOLUTION: Turns out, the Double-Click speed is set too high.  Go into
>   Control Panel > Mouse, Speed, and back it down a little.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case on my instance - it can't be double clicked, it just has the drop down.

Comment: Would you be able to upload a screen shot?

Comment: Sure: http://imgur.com/a/3WAtz

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Great, glad I could help!